# Time estimates on building overviews for mosaic datasets

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I'm trying to create some time estimates for imagery caching in ArcGIS 10.  Does anyone know of any forumlas or ratios to calculate the time it takes to generate overviews for a mosaic dataset?

Does it have anything to do with the area, resolution, file size etc of the actual imagery, or is there even a way to calculate a time estimate for overview generation?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Does anyone have experience in building overviews on massive mosaic dataset (upwards of 9,000 images) in arcGIS 10?

I'm wondering if there is a way to speed up the process ... right now it looks like arcGIS is only using 1 core to build the overviews.  I have a 12 core machine.  Obviously things would go much faster if we can utilize more cores.

My original estimates are blown out of the water ... I'm looking at over 3 weeks to complete this process.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am curious as to what are you trying to do with the mosaic dataset once it is done and why are you choosing to use a mosaic dataset for this specific use case?

Comment: Ragi - I will be caching the imagery.  The mosaic dataset allows me to manage the imagery spanning multiple years.  I can adjust the footprints to eliminate bounding black pixels and also ensure that only the most recent imagery will be displayed.

Comment: Mmm. OK. I was trying to figure out if you could use GDAL directly instead (since it is what ArcGIS uses internally for raster access) to paralellize the process somehow. The operation sounds mostly I/O bound though. Is this correct? If so, for two weeks, you may be better of buying an SSD and processingthe dataset there (if it fits)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think the boss is going to approve the purchase of an SSD!  Definitely reading a lot with this process.  Building overviews is all about resampling tiles.  So at the lowest overview level we read in the affected tiles first, then compute the resampling of the pixels, and output a new image.  Then repeat for the next set of images.  Do you know of any links directing to the use of GDAL in generating overviews?  Anything is worth a try at this point.

Comment: 40+hrs of your time creating a parallel process vs, say, 8hrs of your time walking to the store and buying one and configuring it. Works every time :)

Comment: And of course, first you need to know if we are talking i/o bound operations

Comment: Straight up, an SSD is out of the question.  That is not a good solution to the problem - especially if this method is to be used by other people.  If you do have any info on using GDAL i'd be very interested to read up on it though!

Comment: You are using one core and you have 11 cores to spare. Nevertheless, raster operations are tricky. It is not uncommon to have them being i/o bound instead of cpu bound. You need to figure out if your one CPU is maxed out and the io reads are sparse, then using the other cores makes sense. If your disk read is heavy and your cpu load is load, then there is no point on using the other cores. For example, if the operation you are running writes to only one table in your GDB and that is the bottleneck, then that's important information to offer you a good solution with gdal/parallel processing/etc

Comment: My single core is maxed out right now ... buliding overviews is also computationally expensive as we are in some cases downsampling 4 images

Comment: perfect, so that means you can start by downsampling outside of arcgis using gdal. For example, http://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html builds overviews that will be leveraged transparently by ArcGIS since it is using GDAL already. If you run, say, 6 processes of this tool on different areas simultaneously, you are going to leverage the other cores. In fact, it would be faster than the ArcGIS version since it is skipping the ArcObjects layer

Comment: So I didn't end up using GDAL.  I did however copy my mosaic dataset and run multiple arcgis session to build overviews in parallel.  In arcgis 10.1, you can cache directly from a mosaic dataset without building overviews - so at least that is something to look forward too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We saw overview processing times of similar magnitude when reading/writing to/from a network drive.  Switching to any local drive, even an external USB 2.0, reduced what had been a 2-week process to more like 8 hours.  You shouldn't need an SSD.  It takes some time to transfer all that data locally and back again when you're done, and you have to do a "repair" to get the paths right on the Mosaic Dataset if you move things around this way, but it's still basically an overnight process and a few minutes of setup on either end rather than weeks long.

Comment: Thanks somemaps.  Yea, I've found that the bottleneck in my overview creation was read/write speed rather than CPU speed.  I moved from a network drive to a 10,000rpm hard drive and saw overview creation go from 13 days down to under 4 days.  However, I was still on the hook for transferring the data to an external drive after that.  I will definitely recommend sata/firewire connections for anyone dealing with large volumes of imagery data